# What does ActiveRecord code scope code result in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, activerecord, mongoid

I am trying to implement Push notifications in my Ruby project. I found this code, but cannot tell what it does. In my project I am not using ActiveRecord as I am using MongoDB. The two lines I cannot understand are as follows

```
 scope :android, -> { where(device_type: 'android') }
```

I am not familair with ActiveRecord so is the "-> { where(device_type: 'android') }" a SQL search? What is the result of this code? Wondering how I would implement since I am using MongoDB?

```
 registration_ids= Device.android.map(&:registration_id)
```

The "Device.android.map" where and how is the .android coming from? I am guessing there is a subclass of Device name android?

CODE:

```
rails g model Device registration_id:string device_type:string



    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :android, -> { where(device_type: 'android') }
  ...
  def self.notify_android(data, collapse_key = nil)
    require 'gcm'
    gcm = GCM.new(ENV['API_KEY']) # an api key from prerequisites
    registration_ids= Device.android.map(&:registration_id) # an array of one or more client registration IDs
    options = {
      data: data,
      collapse_key: collapse_key || 'my_app'
    }
    response = gcm.send(registration_ids, options)
  end
  ...
end
```

UPDATE:

Ok, this Android is a commonly used query that can be used as method calls. So now I know what scope does, but not sure how to implement with MongoDB and MongoID.

I think this is correct for rails 4 and MongoID?

```
scope :android, where(:device_type => 'android')
```

So if the above is correct then it leaves one question of what does this mean?

```
&:registration_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read about active record [active record](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#mainCol) to understand what it does. Also have a look at [ORM](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#object-relational-mapping) and [scope](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scope), android is not any subclass it basically

> add a class method for retrieving and querying objects.

so you basically have class method called android on device class

> When you call Device.android it turns into query SELECT "devices".* FROM "devices"  WHERE "devices"."device_type" = 'android' and returns all the records matching where clause.

Before understanding `Device.android.map(&:registration_id)` please have a look at [map](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/map).

> Map returns a new array with the results of running block once for every element in enum.

So basically you are calling `registration_id` on every object which matches filter `device_type = 'android'`. and returns an array of registration ids or in other words we are looping over all objects and collecting registration_id of each object and returning all the collected registration ids.

Answer (score 1):

Read about scope https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scope

A scope represents a narrowing of a database query

In your case

```
registration_ids= Device.android.map(&:registration_id)
```

It will map registration_id of Device whose device_type is 'android'

In &:registration_id & symbol is used to denote that the following argument should be treated as the block given to the method. these is not a proc method so it called it's to_proc method

Device.android.map(&:registration_id.to_proc)

which is same as

Device.android.map { |x| x.registration_id }